# Render twig variables from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, twig, render

I am creating dynamic HTML in JavaScript, for example:

```
var avatarImage = $("<img/>")
    .attr('src', "{{ path('view_photo', {id: photo.id}) }}")
    .attr('width', 42)
    .addClass("avatar");
```

Then I add it to the DOM via jQuery, like this:

```
avatarImage.insertBefore($("#textarea-form-" + entityId));
```

But I obviously need to have it rendered before adding it.

How can I do this?

So I need to render the `{{ path('view_photo', {id: photo.id}) }}`.

Comment: If `photo` is a twig variable as well, you could place  the javascript inside the `twig`-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig template are creating on **back end**. And your javascript can not influence to back-end from browser.

You need create [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request for get ids.